# Format string inside foreach loop

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I am generating an array of strings parsing the response of a web service. This array is used to generate 
[a specific report](https://arogyafinance.com/documents/170/cibil_report.html).

Now, I need to format certain, field values.
Namely payment history 1:  `Payment History 1 : 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000`

Every payment history has a start date and an end date. so, if the difference between payment start and end date is three, then the payment history would have tuple of 3 string each.

`Payment History 1 : 000 000 000`

My objective is to print the name of the month next to each tuple

Like so:

`Payment History 1 : 000(jan) 000(feb) 000(march)`

the challenge being all field and values are being looped through an array `$results` in the view file and i have no idea how to achieve this.

```
@foreach($segment['fields'] as $field)

    <div class="field"> 

        <span class="field_name">
            {{ $field['field_name'] }}
        </span> : 

        @if (stripos($field['field_name'], 'payment history') && !stripos($field['field_name'], 'date') ) 

            <span class="field_value">
                {{ wordwrap($field['field_value'], 3, ' ', true) }}
            </span>
        @else
            <span class="field_value">
                {{ $field['field_value'] }}
            </span>
        @endif

    </div>

@endforeach
```

I am using `wordwrap()` to create the tuple of 3 while printing the value of payment history.

Comment: What are these scary `@` for!?

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski Laravel Blade template engine.

Comment: Right. Missed it is a template not plain code file. Thanks

Comment: So any luck guys?

Comment: would it not be easier to prepare your data before sending it to the view?

Comment: Sure, do you have suggestions?